# UIColor with pattern image and color behind

Tags: ios, uiview, background-color, uicolor

I am trying to set the background color of some `UIView` element.

I would like to paint it with blue color and a dash pattern on top. 
I know I could make a new UIView as its child and paint it with

```
[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:pattern]
```

but I would specifically want one `UIView`, so get one `UIColor` with blue background and pattern image on top.

Marko

EDIT :

Pattern image is  like this : [image]

And the result should be : [image]

Comment: you'll have to subclass UIView and override drawRect method for this

Comment: that I would like to avoid. I have library for some object (bought) and I can't access the view hierarchy. I only can us .backgroundColor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
- (UIImage *)image:(UIImage *)image withColor:(UIColor *)color {
    CGSize backgroundSize = image.size;
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(backgroundSize);
    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGRect backgroundRect;
    backgroundRect.size = backgroundSize;
    backgroundRect.origin.x = 0;
    backgroundRect.origin.y = 0;
    float r,g,b,a;
    [color getRed:&r green:&g blue:&b alpha:&a];
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(ctx, r, g, b, a);
    CGContextFillRect(ctx, backgroundRect);

    CGRect imageRect;
    imageRect.size = image.size;
    imageRect.origin.x = (backgroundSize.width - image.size.width)/2;
    imageRect.origin.y = (backgroundSize.height - image.size.height)/2;

    // Unflip the image
    CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, 0, backgroundSize.height);
    CGContextScaleCTM(ctx, 1.0, -1.0);

    CGContextSetBlendMode(ctx, kCGBlendModeMultiply);
    CGContextDrawImage(ctx, imageRect, image.CGImage);

    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return newImage;
}
```

use above method a s follows

```
 UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Z2AmQ.png"];
 [self.tmpView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[self image:img withColor:[UIColor blueColor]]]];
```

Comment: Wow this is working. Just out of curiosity what is more efficient way to do that with your code or to create new UIView on top with pattern, for all other projects ? :D

Comment: It depends it is only for designing purpose then I think adding 2 views is unnecessary. But I dont know exactly which is the best method  in terms of performance :)

Comment: This code is working for me in iphone 4s and 5 simulators only.  Also, there is a few warnings about CGContextSaveGState, CGContextSetBlendMode and others, saying: Invalid context 0x0...Serious error...contributing to overall degredation...Fatal Error in upcoming update.  Do you have any workarounds? @PratyushaTerli