# UIColor with pattern and colour

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, uicolor

I'm using the code from this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19806781/uicolor-with-pattern-image-and-color-behind)

I am trying to create a colour with a pattern and a colour. I am trying to put the pattern on the existing colour, that is to avoid making 2 views for each view.
This code is working however only if the opacity is under 1.
If its 1 then you can't see the pattern at all. It's like the patters is under the colour somehow. Any idea what am I doing wrong?

```
+ (UIImage *)patternWithimage:(UIImage *)image withColor:(UIColor *)color {
    CGSize backgroundSize = image.size;
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(backgroundSize);
    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGRect backgroundRect;
    backgroundRect.size = backgroundSize;
    backgroundRect.origin.x = 0;
    backgroundRect.origin.y = 0;
    CGFloat r,g,b,a;
    [color getRed:&r green:&g blue:&b alpha:&a];
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(ctx, r, g, b, a);
    CGContextFillRect(ctx, backgroundRect);

    CGRect imageRect;
    imageRect.size = image.size;
    imageRect.origin.x = (backgroundSize.width - image.size.width)/2;
    imageRect.origin.y = (backgroundSize.height - image.size.height)/2;

    // Unflip the image
    CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, 0, backgroundSize.height);
    CGContextScaleCTM(ctx, 1.0, -1.0);

    CGContextSetBlendMode(ctx, kCGBlendModeMultiply);
    CGContextDrawImage(ctx, imageRect, image.CGImage);

    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return newImage;
}
```